# Need help with JasaTeX Author-Year style not indenting references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, indentation

I am really new to LaTeX and I am trying to use the JasaTeX template to format my paper. Everything looks okay, except my reference section. The references should indent the next lines after the first line for each citation, but it's not indenting as it's supposed to. It's just a block of references. I am not sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!Can you prepare an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) that can show us precisely what is going wrong? Are you really sure this is about `biblatex`? The stuff I found on JasaTeX seems to use BibTeX only (it does provide two different `.bst` style files).